# How to get the request from Postman's Get Access Token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, postman

I am successfully getting Postman's Get Access Token feature to work. I need to see the request it's making, though, so I can make the call in code.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: by any chance were you able to achieve it?

Comment: I found a way to get the Chrome Developer Tools debugger to work within the native Postman app.

http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/enabling-chrome-developer-tools-inside-postman/

Comment: The answers below don't seem to work. Anyone figure this out? I ended up just using fiddler.

Comment: @Rafi My comment above yours is what worked for me a while ago. Not sure if that still works or not.

Comment: no didn't work for me. It didn't show the request in the network tab.

Answer (score 6):

You can view a token request by opening the postman console.

**View > Show Postman console** (ALT + CTRL + C)

The postman console holds all your request logs, to make it easier you can clear all the request using the clear button in the top right corner. When you make the token request for your call, it will show up here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "Get Access Token", you can build new POST request to generate TOKEN and make use of POSTMAN code snippet feature to generate the code.[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is a `Code` button on the right hand side of the browser in orange.

[image]

When you click that you should get the code snippet of the request:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for the Get Access Token feature in Authorization.

Comment: Clearly this does not answer the question. The Code button shows only the details of the request that USES the token, not the request (post) that gets the token in the first place